# Retrieve all records if no record exist in the joining table

Tags: sql, join

I have these three tables,

PO_HEADER

| po_number | vendor_name |
| --- | --- |
| 10001 | Xyz |
| 100002 | ABC |

PO_LINEITEM

| line_number | po_number | item_quantity | recieved_quantity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0001 | 10001 | 20 | 10 |
| 0002 | 10001 | 80 | 10 |
| 0002 | 10002 | 40 | 35 |

SHIPMENT_LINEITEM

| line_number | po_number | shipping_quant |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0001 | 10001 | 20 |

How to retrieve order_master based on these two conditions

1. if any po_lineitem having item_quantity > recieved quantity.
2. if po_lineitem having item_quantity > (sum of previously shippingquantity from asn_lineitem for same line_number & poNumber) .2(b) if there no items in the asn_lineitem this should return true.

I wrote this query but was not able to achieve 2(b)

```
select count(*) from erp_po_header 
where po_number in
(select erlitms.po_number from erp_po_line_items erlitms
JOIN
   (select sum(shipping_quantity) as total_prev_shipped_items,po_number,item_number from 
  asn_lineitem
  Group by po_number,item_number) 
   asn_items 
 ON erlitms.po_number = asn_items.po_number
and erlitms.item_number = asn_items.item_number
and erlitms.item_quantity > CAST (erlitms.received_quantity AS INTEGER)
and erlitms.item_quantity > asn_items.total_prev_shipped_items )
```

Comment: . . I don't understand the second condition.  How is "previously shipped" determined?  Your sample data has no date.  What is `asn_lineitem`?  It is not defined.

Comment: Your query, description and sample table names do not align, suggest you proof-read and add some clarity.